# Ruby on Rails: Passing id from view to controller via "link_to"

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2

In an "index" view (no form_for) I have a link_to line, where I want to pass an id to a 
controller for multistep forms:

```
<%= link_to user.username, useredit_steps_path(:id => user.id)  %>
```

I try to read this "id" in the controller with the following line:

```
@user = User.find_by_id(params[:id])
```

However, I always retrieve '0' as a value - which is wrong.

What I am doing wrong?

To be more precise:

Sorry, this dos not help.

Here is my routes.rb file 
    FISneo::Application.routes.draw do resources :useredit_steps

```
resources :age_classes
resources :member_statuses
resources :flights
resources :aircrafts
resources :aircraft_classes
resources :takeoff_types


get "password_resets/new"
get "sessions/new"
get "users/new"

get "log_out" => "sessions#destroy", :as => "log_out"
get "log_in" => "sessions#new", :as => "log_in"
get "sign_up" => "users#new", :as => "sign_up"

resources :sessions
resources :password_resets

resources :users
resources :flight_types

root :to => "sessions#new"
end
```

The URL is: ".......:3000/useredit_steps.3"

Here "3" is an id of one user...

THanks in advance, DIrk

Answer (score 1):

From the Wicked readme:

> Note: Wicked uses the :id parameter to control the flow of steps

In other words, you can't pass anything to the routes helper methods that would overwrite the :id parameter, which is what you are doing above. Try using a different symbol for the key, and it needs to be in a hash passed as the second argument (you will need to pass the id of the first wizard step as the first argument in order to supply the options hash in the second argument). I.e.

```
<%= link_to user.username, useredit_steps_path(:first_step, :user_id => user.id)  %>
```

where :first_step is replaced by the first element of your steps array

Then in the controller, read it out with

```
@user = User.find_by_id(params[:user_id])
```

Sorry I couldn't have seen and answered this months ago, just found the question searching on a similar issue. Figured it was worth posting for others who might land here.

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= link_to user.username, useredit_step_path(user.id)  %>
```

`useredit_step_path` is singular, not plural, if you want to display a specific user.

Comment: Sorry, does not work. Se my post above with more precise information.

Thanks for helping so far....

Comment: Your URL is strange, should be `useredit_steps/3`. Can you try removing the `resources :useredit_steps` and put `match useredit_steps/:id => "usereditsteps#index" instead

Comment: No, does not help. And I do not have an "index" method. "Wicked" requires a "show" method in the controller..... I even have now the URL right and I can see that the SQL is retrieving the right id....

Comment: Yeah sorry I meant `#show` of course. So, everything works fine now?

Comment: Nope. It dos not help...

If I do this I get a "Missing Template" error message. The problem is that Wicked creates different views which are named after the name of the individual steps of the multistep forms....

However, I can see that with your hint the right id is coming to the controller - but with the wrong template rendered....

Comment: Edited my answer `useredit_steps_path` should be `useredit_step_path`. Tell me if that fixes your problem

Comment: No, it does not help... He is looking for the "edit" form, but the way "wicked" works (as I understand) he needs the "show", respective, the individual steps forms... Error Message is as follows:


Template is missing

Missing template useredit_steps/3, application/3 with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee]}. Searched in: * "/Users/dirkb/Sites/FISneo/app/views"

Comment: Add. Info....

If I am using "useredit_steps_path(user.id) the right method in the controller will be called - but, he does not get the proper id. It is always "0" which is wrong. Is it so difficult to send an id from a view to a controller?